# Mobile Content Stuck in Middle of the Page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, positioning

I'm not sure why it's doing this but my jumbotron and my nav are all pushing to the left side of the screen and even making their position absolute and top, right of 0 isn't helping. The furthest they'll go is the middle of the page. I've added a picture of the problem as well as my HTML and CSS code.

[image: Mobile Example]

```css
body {
    max-height: 1050px;
    font-family: 'Biryani', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    overflow: scroll;
}

/* Navbar Style */
.navbar {
    margin-left: 104px;
    margin-right: 104px;
    border: none;
    min-height: 140px;    
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
    margin-top: 24px;
    width: 286px;
    height: 70px;
}

.navbar-default {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    margin-top: 54px;
    padding: 32px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #173b6d;
    border-right: 1px solid #dedee0; 
    border-image: linear-gradient(to top, #dedee0, rgba(222, 222, 224, 0)) 1 100%;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:last-child>a {
    border-right: 0;
}

/* Hero Style */
.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../img/image.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 768px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.jumbotron .h1, .jumbotron h1{
    margin-top: 247px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 60px;
}

.h3, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #d8d9db;
}

/* Button Style */
.btn-primary {
    background-color: #ee4e5a;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 54px;   
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #d34551
}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    font-family: 'Biryani', sans-serif;
}

.btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
    margin-top: 18px;
    width: 221px;
    box-shadow: -4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#btn-clock {
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 28px;
    width: 54px;
    background-color: #d34551;
}

#btn-cta {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 24px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

/* Section Style */
#slant{
    background-color: #0e4375;
}

#slant:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 715px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 316px;
    background: #0e4375;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-4.5deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-4.5deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-4.5deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(-4.5deg);
    transform: skewY(-4.5deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: initial;
}

section {
    top: 786px;
    padding-bottom: 96px;
    background: #0e4375;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

section>h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;  
}

section>p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 270px;
    margin-right: 270px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Media Queries */

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    .navbar {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>yourlogo | Home</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Biryani:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img alt="yourlogo" src="img/logo.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">solutions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- end navbar-collapse -->
        </div> <!-- end container-fluid -->
    </nav>  
    
    <!-- Hero Image -->
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Main Headline Here</h1>
            <h3>Pellentesque augue erat, condimentum eget, ornare ut dui</h3>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-clock">
                    <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-cta">
                    Call to Action
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
      
    <!-- Section -->
    <div class="text-center" id="slant">
        <section>
            <h2>Section Headline</h2>
            <p>Vivamus feugiat eros eu augue dapibus aliquam. Cras at magna efficitur, consectetur sapien eu, convallis metus. Curabitur eusimod orci nec malesuada iaculis. Pellentesque augue erat, condimentum sit amet porta eget, ornare ut dui. Vestibulum feugiat vel ipsum at ullamcorper. Cras at magna efficitur, consectetur sapien eu, convallis metus.</p>
        </section>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem resides in your #slant CSS id telling your text to shift 270px right on a 320 pixel wide screen.

[image link (I don't have 10 rep, yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsRlh.png)

If you hover over the  element with the inspector it should tell you that the element is 320 pixels wide, despite what it may look like.

[another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcv5M.png)

I'm probably wrong, though, but I can't be sure because I couldn't replicate your site with the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Put `width: 100%;` on `section`. The paragraph inside that section has too much margin on left and right sides which is creating this issue on smaller screen sizes.

```css
body {
    max-height: 1050px;
    font-family: 'Biryani', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    overflow: scroll;
}

/* Navbar Style */
.navbar {
    margin-left: 104px;
    margin-right: 104px;
    border: none;
    min-height: 140px;    
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
    margin-top: 24px;
    width: 286px;
    height: 70px;
}

.navbar-default {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    margin-top: 54px;
    padding: 32px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #173b6d;
    border-right: 1px solid #dedee0; 
    border-image: linear-gradient(to top, #dedee0, rgba(222, 222, 224, 0)) 1 100%;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:last-child>a {
    border-right: 0;
}

/* Hero Style */
.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../img/image.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 768px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.jumbotron .h1, .jumbotron h1{
    margin-top: 247px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 60px;
}

.h3, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #d8d9db;
}

/* Button Style */
.btn-primary {
    background-color: #ee4e5a;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 54px;   
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #d34551
}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    font-family: 'Biryani', sans-serif;
}

.btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
    margin-top: 18px;
    width: 221px;
    box-shadow: -4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#btn-clock {
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 28px;
    width: 54px;
    background-color: #d34551;
}

#btn-cta {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 24px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

/* Section Style */
#slant{
    background-color: #0e4375;
}

#slant:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 715px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 316px;
    background: #0e4375;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-4.5deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-4.5deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-4.5deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(-4.5deg);
    transform: skewY(-4.5deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: initial;
}

section {
    top: 786px;
    padding-bottom: 96px;
    background: #0e4375;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

section>h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;  
}

section>p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 270px;
    margin-right: 270px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Media Queries */

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    .navbar {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>yourlogo | Home</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Biryani:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img alt="yourlogo" src="img/logo.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">solutions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- end navbar-collapse -->
        </div> <!-- end container-fluid -->
    </nav>  
    
    <!-- Hero Image -->
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Main Headline Here</h1>
            <h3>Pellentesque augue erat, condimentum eget, ornare ut dui</h3>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-clock">
                    <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-cta">
                    Call to Action
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
      
    <!-- Section -->
    <div class="text-center" id="slant">
        <section>
            <h2>Section Headline</h2>
            <p>Vivamus feugiat eros eu augue dapibus aliquam. Cras at magna efficitur, consectetur sapien eu, convallis metus. Curabitur eusimod orci nec malesuada iaculis. Pellentesque augue erat, condimentum sit amet porta eget, ornare ut dui. Vestibulum feugiat vel ipsum at ullamcorper. Cras at magna efficitur, consectetur sapien eu, convallis metus.</p>
        </section>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```